# Simple jQuery If then

Tags: jquery

Losing my mind on this one..

How can I do something as simple as..

If div has class "something" then make div#test have a class of "awesome"

```
<div class="something">hey there</div>

<div id="test">Am I awesome?</div>
```

Much Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "if a div exists with a class of .something", or if a particular div has a class of .something? If it's the second one, then I think you'll need to give the first div an ID.

Comment: You will either need to give your first DIV an identifier (ID) or you'll find people just find the first DIV, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($("div.something").length) {
    $("div#test").addClass("awesome");
}
```

Comment: Note that this will add the awesome class if there is one (or more) DIVs on the page with the "something" CSS class.

Comment: Makes Sense. If there is more than one div with the class name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the class of a particular div, then change your html

```
<div id="im_special" class="something">hey there</div>
```

and then look for the id in the javascript

```
if ($("div#im_special.something").length) {
    $("div#test").addClass("awesome");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a .hasClass() method that is useful, albeit maybe not exactly what you are looking for.

[hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)